# MySQL - Enabling Scheduled Event on Master and Slave Simultaneously

Tags: replication, mysql-5.5, mysql-event

This may seem a bit strange, but I am trying to get a `Scheduled Event` to execute on both Master and Slave.

I have two databases set up in a Master (A) to Master (B) replication environment.

Master A is `READ_ONLY=OFF`

Master B is `READ_ONLY=ON`

I create a user on both Databases:
`GRANT INSERT, EVENT ON test.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';`

I then create my Event on Master A:

```
DROP EVENT `e_test`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` 
EVENT `e_test` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE 
STARTS NOW() 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE 
ENABLE 
COMMENT 'Adds a new row to test.tab1 every 1 minute' 
DO 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO test.tab1 (`fname`) VALUES (NOW());
    END;
$$
```

So far so good. It executes every minute, and adds an entry to the table, which replicates to the other Database.

However, on the Master B, it is marked as `SlaveSide Disabled`, and so doesn't execute.

If I do:

`ALTER DEFINER=user@localhost EVENT e_test ENABLE;`

on Master B, it starts to execute on Master B, but on Master A it is now flagged as `Slaveside_Disabled`, and so doesn't execute.

If I then enable it on Master A, Master B is `Slaveside_Disabled`.

The reason for wanting this (in case you were wondering), is so that as part of my failover script I simply need to execute `SET GLOBAL READ_ONLY = { ON | OFF }` on each database accordingly, 
as opposed to having to enable / disable all my events (one command vs many commands).

Under normal circumstances, on Master A (`READ_ONLY=OFF`) the events execute as per normal and adds the entry; On Master B (`READ_ONLY=ON`) the events execute, but don't insert an entry as they don't have permission.

I looked at using `SET GLOBAL EVENT_SCHEDULER = { ON | OFF }` as the one command, but if I set it to `OFF` as the default, then we need to remember to enable it each server restart. 
Alternatively if we set it to `ON` as the default we need to remember to disable it every server restart.
The use of `READ_ONLY` seemed a better option as it can be easily included in a failover script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to do this so far is by using:

On the Master B:

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;
ALTER DEFINER=user@localhost EVENT e_test ENABLE;
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=1;
```

This works, but as soon as I alter the Event on Master A, Master B goes back to `Slaveside_disabled` and I have to repeat this process. So not perfect by any means, as it relies on us remembering to do this for each event, if we `Alter` them.